# Nested fragment inside a listview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-tabs

I'm a perfect newbie and I'm trying to develop a simple Android app in which I have an activity with scrollable tabs + swipe navigation. Each tab should create a fragment with a listview inside and on clicking to an item of the list I should recreate another fragment with a new listview related to the item I had clicked before.
How can I do that in the simpliest way?
Do you have a really easy guide where I can refer to?

Comment: Try this sample: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

Comment: I'm checking that sample out and it's is exactly what eclipse has already done for me, I need a next step that is: I inserted a viewlist in every fragment and I need to recreate another list from the selected item of the previous list. In another words, it's like to pass my data from an activity to another one just created from the previous one. I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bundle to pass data from one activity to another activity. The other way is using shared preferences, content providers, serialization. It all depends on what kind of data you need to pass and how big the data is.

What have you tried and where are you stuck. If you could post code, happy to help further.